# Open workbook from another workbook without firing the open workbook event?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks integrated into the following workflow:

```
1. I export data from WB1 into WB2
2. I want to check, whether the data in WB2 are up to date.
```

In my VBA Code in `WB1` I use

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\WorkbookName.xls"
```

to get my data from `WB1` into `WB2`.

In `WB2` I have `VBA` Code within the `Open Event` to check it the data is up to date.

**PROBLEM:** If I use `Workbooks.Open "C:\WorkbookName.xls"` the `Open Event` fires. Is it possible to avoid that and to manipulate the `WB2` from `WB1` without to activate the `Open Event`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by disabling the events before opening the file:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

After opening the file you can enable the events again:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Correct. The aforementioned lines should be put into the WB1 code.